# Select option by text

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble setting my selects to some default values that come in through ajax

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/helto/wycLZ/

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div>
<label id="conditionLabel" for="condition">Condition:</label>
<select id="condition">
    <option selected="true" style="display:none;">Choose</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var conditions = [{
id: 1,
name: "New"
}, {
id: 2,
name: "Good"
}, {
id: 3,
name: "Poor"
}];
$.each(conditions, function (key, value) {
var cond = '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>';
$('#condition').append(cond);
});

$('#condition option[text="New"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Its this last line that's giving me trouble, I want to select the option based on the text

Comment: You can't use selectors like that. They can't see the contents of an element, only it's attributes

Comment: @Jivings: jQuery has the `:contains()` selector.

Comment: @Blender Oh yes, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `:contains`:

```
$('#condition option:contains("New")').prop('selected', true);
```

Or `.filter()`:

```
$('#condition option').filter(function() {
    return this.text === 'New';
}).prop('selected', true);
```

`:contains` will match `News` as well, so I'd go with `.filter()`

Comment: prop() maybe, otherwise +1 for the filter ??

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$('#condition option:contains("New")').prop('selected', true);` which takes advantage of [jQuery's :contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Here is a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wycLZ/2/)**